# Is it possible to change color of specified text in MaterializeCSS Tooltip?

Tags: css, materialize

I'd like to ask if it's possible to change text color in tooltip while there's an specified text? For example, if:

```
data-tooltip="OFFLINE"
```

I'd like text to be red, BUT when

```
data-tooltip="ONLINE"
```

I'd like text to be green, I tried to do something inside my own CSS file like `[data-tooltip=OFFLINE]`, but it didn't work... I would be so glad if you guys helped me solving that, if it's even possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont think by default materializecss support css classes for Tooltip. One solution for this can be is to modify the materialize js library. I did the same while facing similar issue for materialize Select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they are using jquery tooltip : visit this link

[styling tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your talking about this [framwork](http://materializecss.com) http://materializecss.com.

Here is my version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593605/materialize-css-tooltip/43016060#43016060) ...

**HTML**

```
<i class="material-icons tooltipped" 
data-position="bottom" 
data-tooltip="HAVE IT" 
data-background-color="white" 
data-text-color="grey-text">check</i>
```

**JS**

```
$('.tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 50}).each(function () {
    var background = $(this).data('background-color');
    if (background) {
        $("#" + $(this).data('tooltip-id')).find(".backdrop").addClass(background);
    };
    var text = $(this).data('text-color');
    if (text) {
        $("#" + $(this).data('tooltip-id')).find("span").addClass(text);
    };
});
```